# C++ header and class file - undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, class, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

.h:

```
class ArithmeticCoding
{
public:
    ArithmeticCoding();
    static void test(QString text);

    static QMap<QChar,int> letters_freq;
}
```

.cpp:

```
QMap<QChar, int> letters_freq;

ArithmeticCoding::ArithmeticCoding()
{
}

void ArithmeticCoding::test(QString text)
{
    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) letters_freq[text.at(i)]++;
}
```

I am getting

> arithmeticcoding.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to
>   `ArithmeticCoding::letters_freq'

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to exactly one of your CPPs

```
 QMap<QChar,int> ArithmeticCoding::letters_freq;
```

Comment: Ahhh! I knew something simple is missing :)